# how to draw a semitransparent cuboid with an image inside?

Tags: matrix, graphics3d, tensors

I want to draw a cube with a specific opacity and an Image placed inside it. My plan was to use those cubes as building blocks of a 3 dimensional representation of a 3 rank tensor ( more or less like this
 [image: http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/janetw/cmc/chapters/Hebbian/ten3.gif]).

I can easily draw the cubes in the right spots but placing the images inside them is beyond my ability. how can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: There was a useful question about placing text in fixed positions in 3d in a non-rotating manner, and taking into account the distance from the observer, but I cannot find it :(

Comment: damn :-(. if i could insert a plane in the cuboid and  draw the 2d image on that plane i could use this trick to solve the problem

Comment: Why not to use something like `Graphics3D[Cuboid /@ Position[BoxMatrix[All, {5, 5, 5}], 1]]`? Do you really need `Raster`?

Comment: well i need to place numbers on the boxes and make them transparent otherwise  i can't see the numbers in the central part of the cube

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.02], 
    Map[Cuboid, Position[BoxMatrix[All, {5, 5, 5}], 1]]}];
pos1 = Position[BoxMatrix[All, {5, 5, 5}], 1];
pos2 = ({0, .75, .25} + #) & /@ pos1;
g2 = Graphics3D[{Text["A", #] & /@ pos2}];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]